# C++ request for member (blank) in (blank) , which is of non-class type (blank) when calling method

Tags: c++, function, methods, struct

I'm trying to learn about artificial neural networks using this page(It's in Processing but i'm converting it to C++ while changing some minor parts): http://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-10-neural-networks/ But when I run the code down below I get this error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:36:7: error: request for member ‘feedforward’ in ‘idk’, which is of non-class type ‘Perceptron()’
  idk->feedforward({1.0, .5});
```

I've looked around but I dont think I can find someone that gets this error while calling a method.
Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>

const double e = 2.71828182845904523536;

float S(float in){
    return 1 / (1 + pow(e, -(in)));
}

double fRand(double fMin, double fMax){
    double f = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
    return fMin + f * (fMax - fMin);
}

struct Perceptron{ 
    Perceptron(int n);
    std::vector<double> weights;
    int feedforward(float inputs[]);
};

Perceptron::Perceptron (int n){
    weights.assign(n, fRand(-1.0, 1.0));
}

int Perceptron::feedforward(float inputs[]){
    return 0; // I have this just for testing that I can call it
}

int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));

    Perceptron idk();
    idk.feedforward({1.0, .5});

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The most vexing parse strikes again! :P

Comment: @Rakete1111 If there is a deeper wisdom in that, it is beyond me. Could you elaborate?

Comment: The line `Perceptron idk();` isn't a declaration of an object named `idk`; it's a function prototype for a function that takes no arguments and returns a `Perceptron`. Delete the parentheses to fix this.

Comment: Don't vandalise your own post to remove the source of the error. It makes the question unintelligible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Perceptron idk();` is a declaration of a function, not an object. Either pass constructor parameters to `idk` or make a default constructor that takes no argument. From your code it appears that you intended to use have `Perceptron` with a default ctor, so you should probably remove `()` from you `idk` declaration to make it a declaration of an object instead of a function and remove `int n` from `Perceptron` constructor.

Comment: The name of this common issue is "most vexing parse".